# How to write w3c complaint angularjs code

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, w3c, w3c-validation

When i validate one page developed in angularjs in w3c validator, I am getting these errors:

How to write w3c complaint angular code to pass the test?

[1]: [Error screenshot][1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG8K4.png

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Such things disappear over time. Please copy the errors and post them here.